# saving unicode to database

Tags: python, mysql, django, unicode

I am trying to save the following string to mysql database using django (I got the string from somewhere else)

```
m.cr1 = u"\U0001F3C9" # cr1 is models.CharField(max_length=50)
m.save()
```

I get the error

```
Warning: Incorrect string value: '\xF0\x9F\x8F\x89' for column 'cr1' at row 1
```

I've looked on other related questions here, and change mysql to be utf8_unicode_ci, but this does not help. In general, my code works ok with unicode, but not in this specific case.

I guess that this is related to the fact that this is 32 bits unicode.

I actually just want to detect this case, and maybe to ignore the bad characters.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: This [post](http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/mysql-utf8mb4) might help you too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MySQL `utf8` is not the real UTF-8, but a modified one that only supports code points up to `0xFFFF`. You are trying to use a code point (`0x1F3C9` > `0xFFFF`) that is not included in MySQL `utf8`.

You need to have relatively new version of MySQL, and change `utf8` to `utf8mb4`. Everywhere.

The connection needs to be `utf8mb4`, the collation, the tables/columns and so on. Anywhere you have `utf8` in MySQL context is wrong and needs to be `utf8mb4`.